# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

I'm extremely new to Python and this is my first real project. I am trying to make a web crawler and getting this error

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page < max_pages:
         url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + str(page)
         source_code = requests.get(url)
         plain_text = source_code.text
         soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findAll("a"):
        href = link.get("href")
        print(href)
    page += 1

main_spider(1)
```

Here is the error

```
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation on the posted code? It looks like the `for` loop is not in the `while` loop. In the case where the `while` is never true, `soup` is never assigned and you get the error. But the real problem is you want to process soup inside the while.

Comment: `while page <+ max_pages:` you don't need that `+`

Comment: Code now indented above.  How do I process the soup inside the while?  Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: Python uses indentation to figure out what is inside or outside of a loop. Right now, the `for` is at the same level as the `while`, meaning that it will only execute after the `while` has completed. Make it line up with `soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)` to run in the loop.

Comment: Wow thanks no more error!  However I don't get anything back from the code just a blank interpreter?

Comment: Consider also that you only process if `page <+ max_pages`. But when you call the function, `main_spider(1)`, that sets `max_pages` to 1. `pages` is 1, `max_pages` is 1, so the loop never runs. I think you want to change the  loop to `while page <= max_pages`. More idomatically, you can use a for loop instead: `for page in range(1, max_pages+1):`.

Comment: Perfect I changed the while loop to a for loop!  Thanks so much!  Any way I can mark a comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnboundLocalError` means there is a code path where a local variable is not assigned before use. In this case, `soup` is used after a `while` loop assigning the variable completes. The code doesn't consider the case where the `while` loop never runs.

That exposes other bugs. First, the `for` loop should be indented so that it runs inside the `while`. Second, why didn't the outer loop run? That was simply a case of a typo in the conditional: `<+` should have been `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page < max_pages:
         url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + str(page)
         source_code = requests.get(url)
         plain_text = source_code.text
         soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
         for link in soup.findAll("a"):
             href = link.get("href")
             print(href)
    page += 1

main_spider(1)
```

In your case, `soup` has a local scope of the while loop, so you can only access it inside the while.

Since it appears you're doing soup on single pages (and using the while loop to move between pages), I believe you want your `soup.findAll('a')` to be inside the while loop (AKA on a per page basis).