# send an in-memory chart object to Excel file

Tags: python, openpyxl

Sorry, I'm a newbie so please be gentle. Is there a way to send an in-memory file (generated using Matplotlib) to an Excel file? I'm trying to do this using openpyxl but no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks!

I hacked on the following code to produce in-memory chart object:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2])
plt.title("test")
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
im = Image.open(buf)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('input.xlsx')
ws = wb.active


ws.add_image(im, 'A1')
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Unfortunately, this produced the following error message:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rel' referenced before assignment

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Note: the following works but is inefficient.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('input.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('my_chart.png')
ws.add_image(img, 'A1')
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Welcome, you must have a variable `rel` somewhere in your code, but I could not see it. The answer will roughly be like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531614/4636715), but for a more detailed investigation, we should see that `rel` I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Strange as it may seem, there is no variable 'rel' in my code.  Also, please note that I corrected the second to last line of my code which was missing the 'im' variable.  The error message is the same and I remain confused. Note: using openpyxl, the following code will call and send a png file to an Excel file.  However, it seems rather cumbersome and inefficient to create and save a png file to a directory on my hard drive and then call it and, in turn, send it to an Excel file.  Highly inefficient when working with a multitude of matplotlib charts.

Comment: Sorry, the code that works, which I referenced in my previous comment, was added to the code in my initial question (see above).  Thanks!

Comment: Always provide the full traceback of an error to help us understand exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the image handling code currently requires file paths. You can see where this is required if you look at the full traceback provided.

It's actually no less efficient to use temporary files for the images instead of in-memory images so I'd advise doing this anyway.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I did in the end.  Specifically, I imported os and then added a statement to remove the temporary file which I don't want cluttering my hard drive:  os.remove("my_chart.png").

Comment: You might want to look at the `tempfile` which is designed for just such situations, including cleanup (and is used in openpyxl).

Answer (score 2):

At least since v2.6.2 of openpyxl it is totally possible to insert in-memory images without requiring temporary file saving to fool the handling code. The problem was that add_image() needs the right Image object.
Here is the working code sample:

```
import io
#from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2])
plt.title("test")
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
#im = Image.open(buf)
im = Image(buf)
im.anchor = 'A1'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('input.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws.add_image(im)
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use io.ByteIO and penpyxl.drawing.image.Image to write picture data into an excel without any temporary disk storage.

```
import io
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = book.active

# do something here

image     = io.BytesIO(your_picture_data)
image_xls = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(image)
sheet.add_image(image_xls, 'A1')

# do something here
```